# Dojo's DataGrid content with position: absolute - how to controll this behaviour?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm testing **Dojo 1.9**. I've created a sample - data grid, placed below some text, search field and button. The problem is, that the content of the grid has been displayed over the whole content of the page. I've quickly found the offending fragment:

```
<div role="presentation" dojoattachpoint="scrollboxNode" class="dojoxGridScrollbox" style="height: 15px;">
    <div role="presentation" hidefocus="hidefocus" dojoattachpoint="contentNode" class="dojoxGridContent" style="height: 750px; width: 1260px;">
        <div role="presentation" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; position: absolute;">
        .......
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

OK, now I understand, but the documentation: https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/populating_datagrid/ says nothing about such behaviour. After **removing** the `position:absolute` I have a good starting point.

So my question is, why is this absolute positioning used in the first line, and the second, more important: **how to get rid of it?**

Here is the code I'm using to create the data grid:

```
grid = new DataGrid({
    store : dataStore,
    items: data.result,
    queryOptions : {},
    structure : [{
        name : "First Name",
        field : "vorname",
        width : "100px"
    }, {
        name : "Last Name",
        field : "nachname",
        width : "100px"
    }]
});
$('#grid').append(grid.domNode);
grid.startup();
```